# Error al validar un formulario con JavaScript al presionar una tecla o perder el foco

Tags: javascript, jquery, formularios

Estoy intentado poner una validación del lado del cliente de unos formularios de mi página web, incluso añadiéndole una clase para mostrar el error, o ya por desesperación he añadido un `document.write`.

Tal es la cosa que estas serían mis validaciones y éste mi código. No sé por dónde tengo el fallo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //variables globales
  var acronimo = $("#acronimo");
  var categoria = $("#categoria");

});

//funciones de validación

function validateAcronimo() {
  //No cumple longitud máxima-minima
  if (acronimo.val().length <= 4) {
    acronimo.addClass("error");
    document.write("Prueba");
    return false;
  }
  //Si lognitud pero no caracteres
  else if (!acronimo.val().match(/^[A-Z]+$/)) {
    acronimo.addClass("error");
    return false;
  }
  //Si longitud, si caracteres
  else {
    acronimo.removeClass("error");
    return false;
  }
}

function validateCategoria() {
  //Longitud máxima
  if (categoria.val().length <= 50) {
    categoria.addClass("error");
    return false;
  }
  //Si
  else {
    categoria.removeClass("error");
    return false;
  }
}

//Perdida de foco
acronimo.blur(validateAcronimo);
categoria.blur(validateCategoria);

//Pulsacion de tecla
acronimo.keyup(validateAcronimo);
categoria.keyup(validateCategoria);
// Envio de formulario  
$("#form1").submit(function() {
  if (validateAcronimo() & validateCategoria())
    return true;
  else
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.js"></script>

<form id="form1 " action="?action=<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? 'actualizar' : 'registrar'; ?>" method="POST" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('acronimo') : ''; ?>" />

  <table style="width:500px;">
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align:left;">Acronimo</th>
      <td><input id="acronimo" class="requisites" type="text" name="acronimo" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('acronimo') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>

      <th style="text-align:left;">Categoria</th>
      <td><input id="categoria" class="requisites" type="text" name="categoria" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('categoria') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button></td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <form action="index.php">
          <input class="btn btn-primary" type="reset" value="Limpiar" />
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Listo, lo siento por no haber añadido el form

Comment: Ninguno, directamente no muestra ni el document.write ni cambia la clase del css

Comment: Lo que yo veo es que tus variables globales no son accesibles desde los métodos de validación. De hecho solo son accesibles en el método ready.

Comment: La validación de `acronimo` es que sea todo en mayúsculas?

Comment: @mariano creo que eso es irrelevante en su problema porque tiene muchos otros fallos. pero si, los acronimo no tienen que ir en mayusculas... querria decir Siglas?

Comment: @lois6b lo es, sólo era una forma de avisar que, después de arreglar todo eso, no intente validar texto en minúsculas

Comment: @AlbertoCeperodeAndrés como verás, modifiqué un poco el formato de tu pregunta para que sea más sencillo de leer. Sería bueno que lo tomes de ejemplo para futuras preguntas... Lo que sí, al permitir que se ejecute el código sobre tu pregunta, se puede observar el error que aparece en la consola... Esto es una información muy importante, tanto para cuando quieras depurar código, como para cuando quieras realizar una pregunta.

Comment: @mariano y tambien quitaria el php ya que solo intenta introducir un valor, nada de funcionalidad extra

Comment: @lois6b sí, no quise modificarle tanto el código ya que no molestaba, pero es una excelente recomendación: al realizar preguntas de JavaScript, conviene mostrar la respuesta ya procesada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes varios fallos:

1. El form se llama `form1` y lo tienes puesto con espacio
2. No te esta reconociendo las "variables globales" por lo que los eventos no se lanzan
3. En tus comprobaciones nunca devuelves `true`

Notas:

- Creo que la categoria tienes la comprobacion mal, ¿no seria que está bien si es menor que 50 caracteres?
- Te añadí el css de la clase error que no pusiste (un fondo rojo, por ejemplo)
- Ten en cuenta que los [acronimos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acr%C3%B3nimo) no necesariamente tienen que ir todo en mayusculas, a diferencia de las siglas.

```js
var acronimo = $("#acronimo");
var categoria = $("#categoria");


//funciones de validación

function validateAcronimo() {
  //No cumple longitud máxima-minima
  if (acronimo.val().length <= 4) {
    acronimo.addClass("error");
    //document.write("Prueba");
    return false;
  } else {

    //Si lognitud pero no caracteres
    if (!acronimo.val().match(/^[A-Z]+$/)) {
      acronimo.addClass("error");
      return false;
    }
    //Si longitud, si caracteres
    else {
      acronimo.removeClass("error");
      return true;
    }
  }

}

function validateCategoria() {
  //Longitud máxima
  if (categoria.val().length <= 50) {
    categoria.addClass("error");
    return false;
  }
  //Si
  else {
    categoria.removeClass("error");
    return true;
  }
}

//Perdida de foco
acronimo.blur(validateAcronimo);
categoria.blur(validateCategoria);

//Pulsacion de tecla
acronimo.keyup(validateAcronimo);
categoria.keyup(validateCategoria);
// Envio de formulario  
$("#form1").submit(function() {
  if (validateAcronimo() & validateCategoria()) {
    alert("Guardado");
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("No guardado");
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
.error {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" action="" method="POST" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="" />

  <table style="width:500px;">
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align:left;">Acronimo</th>
      <td><input id="acronimo" class="requisites" type="text" name="acronimo" value="" style="width:100%;" required /></td>

      <th style="text-align:left;">Categoria</th>
      <td><input id="categoria" class="requisites" type="text" name="categoria" value="" style="width:100%;" required/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button></td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <form action="index.php">
          <input class="btn btn-primary" type="reset" value="Limpiar" />
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: al igual que le de Asier funciona perfectamente, gracias a los dos por vuestra aydua!

Comment: @AlbertoCeperodeAndrés y si no es indiscreccion, en que te basaste para aceptar una u otra?

Comment: Pues ese es el problema como doy a dos preguntas que estan bien el tick verde, más me esta jodiendo a mi, por que ambos dos no es la primera vez que me resolveis la duda y me jode solo poder darlo a uno.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un problema con el ámbito de las variables. 
Aunque indicas en el comentario que acronimo y categoria son variables globales no lo son. Las defines dentro de una función y por lo tanto únicamente están disponibles dentro del ámbito de la función.

He modificado tu código para inicializar los controladores de eventos dentro del método ready de document e inicializando las variables acronimo y categoría dentro de las funciones de validación:

```js
//funciones de validación

function validateAcronimo() {
    var acronimo = $('#acronimo');
    //No cumple longitud máxima-minima
    if (acronimo.val().length <= 4) {
        acronimo.addClass("error");
        return false;
    }
    //Si lognitud pero no caracteres
    else if (!acronimo.val().match(/^[A-Z]+$/)) {
        acronimo.addClass("error");
        return false;
    }
    //Si longitud, si caracteres
    acronimo.removeClass("error");
    return true;
}
function validateCategoria() {
    var categoria = $('#categoria');
    //Longitud máxima
    if (categoria.val().length <= 50) {
        categoria.addClass("error");
        return false;
    }
    //Si
    categoria.removeClass("error");
    return true;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var acronimo = $("#acronimo");
    var categoria = $("#categoria");

    //Perdida de foco
    acronimo.blur(validateAcronimo);
    categoria.blur(validateCategoria);

    //Pulsacion de tecla
    acronimo.keyup(validateAcronimo);
    categoria.keyup(validateCategoria);
    
    // Envio de formulario  
    $("#form1").submit(function () {
      return validateAcronimo() && validateCategoria();
    });
});
```

```css
.error{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" action="actualizar" method="POST" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
            <input  type="hidden" name="id" value="" />

            <table style="width:500px;">
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align:left;">Acronimo</th>
                    <td><input  id="acronimo" class="requisites" type="text" name="acronimo"  value="" style="width:100%;" required /></td>

                    <th style="text-align:left;">Categoria</th>
                    <td><input id="categoria" class="requisites" type="text" name="categoria"  value="" style="width:100%;" required/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button></td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <form action="index.php">
                            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="reset" value="Limpiar" />
                        </form></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

Comment: Asier, funciona perfectamente, pero unicamente necesito comprender el por que del "$this"

Comment: @AlbertoCeperodeAndrés como va a funcionar si no tiene `return true`?  :/

Comment: Pues funciona correctamente, cuando pones minusculas, te marca en rojo de que esta mal, y cuanod pones mayusculas se pone de su color original por ejemplo, no sabria decirte pero funciona

Comment: bueno, @AlbertoCeperodeAndrés pero el return es a la hora de pulsar guardar hahah

Comment: En realidad no es necesario el return true. Incluso funcionaría realizando un return en lugar del return false cuando se detecta un error. En un controlador de eventos un return false provocará la cancelación del evento en eventos cancelables (como puede ser el submit o el click). En estos casos devolver true y no devolver nada es equivalente. En los eventos no cancelables el valor devuelto no se tiene en cuenta para nada por lo que se puede omitir.

Comment: @AsierVillanueva es necesario para el submit.

Comment: Cierto, ahí sí. No veía a qué os referíais. En el submit había dejado el código tal y como estaba. Había corregido el código de las validaciones. Lo edito para dejarlo en condiciones.